# Static resources not loaded in thymeleaf template

Tags: javascript, css, spring, thymeleaf

I'm newbie to spring thymeleaf and I have a web page which is broken into header, body and footer  but when I try to include header then the css and js are not loaded into the webpage.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
 main
  ├───  java
  ├───  resources
  ├───  web-resources
  │   ├───  css
  │   ├───  jss
  │   └───  views
  └───  webapp
      ├───  META-INF
      └───  resources
          ├───  css
          ├───  jss
          └───  views
```

And my thymeleaf configuration is:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/resources/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
    <!-- Template cache is set to false (default is true). -->
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
</bean>
```

My header css looks like this:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap-min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-min.css}"/>

    <link type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap-theme-min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-theme-min.css}"/>

    <script src="../../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap-min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And the main html is:

```html
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>

    <link type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-min.css}"/>

    <link type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-theme-min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-theme-min.css}"/>

    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap-min.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap-min.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div th:include="fragments/header :: header"></div>
</body>
```

But still when I request page, 404 is displayed for css and jss.

Answer (score 0):

Do not repeat the head element in the fragment. What you are currently doing is trying to append a duplicate head element in body. Include in fragment only the body parts of the header as you'd do in a jsp import.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've resolved the problem by correcting the resource path in my spring mvc configuration but didn't gave thought of duplicate head.
Thanks a lot for pointing out the potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
<script src="../../js/bootstrap-min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: If you use src like "../../js/bootstrap-min.js". It's only used in static html in localhost. When deployed in server, we should get js and css according to the url, like : 'http://localhost:8080/projectName/resource/js/bootstrap-min.js'. After change to "@{/resources/js/bootstrap-min.js", the thymeleaf would explain the url to the right url. You can see it in http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls